# How to convert a nested data structure of TypeA to TypeB using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, algorithm

I have the Folowing Types:

```
class TypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; } // Holds either a primitive DataType or a List<TypeA>
    public string IrrelevantInformation { get; set; }
}

class TypeB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; } //Holds either a primitive DataType or a List<TypeB>
}
```

What I want is to convert a Hirarchical Structure of TypeA to TypeB.

I did it using a conventional recursive method:

```
private TypeB ConvertToTypeB(TypeA Input)
{
    return new TypeB() { Name = Input.Name, Value = ((Input.Value is List<TypeA>) ? ((List<TypeA>)Input.Value).Select(v=>ConvertToTypeB(v)).ToList() : Input.Value) };
}
```

My Question is: Can this be done without the ConvertToTypeB function using only one Linq query?

Comment: LINQ can be useful to convert a _sequence_ of `TypeA`s into a sequence of `TypeB`s, given that you can convert a single `TypeA` to a `TypeB` (as easy as just `sequenceOfTypeA.Select(ConvertToTypeB)`). But I doubt that the conversion between non-sequences is a LINQ's job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert hieractical structures the recursive call is required.
There is no a way to exclude AtoB method.